# r - Missing object when ggsave output as .svg

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, gridextra, gtable

I'm attempting to step through a dataset and create a histogram and summary table for each factor and save the output as a `.svg` . The histogram is created using `ggplot2` and the summary table using `summary()`.

I have successfully used the code below to save the output to a single `.pdf` with each page containing the relevant histogram/table. However, when I attempt to save each histogram/table combo into a set of `.svg` images using `ggsave` only the `ggplot` histogram is showing up in the `.svg`. The table is just white space.

I've tried using `dev.copy` `Cairo` and `svg` but all end up with the same result:  Histogram renders, but table does not.  If I save the image as a `.png` the table shows up.

I'm using the `iris` data as a reproducible dataset. I'm not using `R-Studio` which I saw was causing some "empty plot" grief for others.

```
#packages used
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
library(Cairo)
#Create iris histogram plot
  iris.hp<-ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth =.25,origin=-0.125,
      right = TRUE,col="white", fill="steelblue4",alpha=1) + 
       labs(title = "Iris Sepal Length")+
        labs(x="Sepal Length", y="Count")
   iris.list<-by(data = iris, INDICES = iris$Species, simplify = TRUE,FUN = function(x) 
     {iris.hp %+% x + ggtitle(unique(x$Species))})

#Generate list of data to create summary statistics table
  sum.str<-aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,summary)
  spec<-sum.str[,1]
  spec.stats<-sum.str[,2]
  sum.data<-data.frame(spec,spec.stats)
  sum.table<-tableGrob(sum.data)
  colnames(sum.data) <-c("species","sep.len.min","sep.len.1stQ","sep.len.med",
  "sep.len.mean","sep.    len.3rdQ","sep.len.max")
  table.list<-by(data = sum.data, INDICES = sum.data$"species", simplify =   TRUE, 
     FUN = function(x) {tableGrob(x)})

#Combined histogram and summary table across multiple plots
 multi.plots<-marrangeGrob(grobs=(c(rbind(iris.list,table.list))),
   nrow=2, ncol=1, top = quote(paste(iris$labels$Species,'\nPage', g, 'of',pages)))

#bypass the class check per @baptiste
ggsave <- ggplot2::ggsave; body(ggsave) <- body(ggplot2::ggsave)[-2]
#
for(i in 1:3){
  multi.plots<-marrangeGrob(grobs=(c(rbind(iris.list[i],table.list[i]))),
    nrow=2, ncol=1,heights=c(1.65,.35),
    top = quote(paste(iris$labels$Species,'\nPage', g, 'of',pages)))
  prefix<-unique(iris$Species)
  prefix<-prefix[i]
  filename<-paste(prefix,".svg",sep="")
  ggsave(filename,multi.plots)
  #dev.off()
}
```

**Edit** removed theme tt3 that @rawr referenced.  It was accidentally left in example code. It was not causing the problem, just in case anyone was curious.

Comment: i ran your code as-is and it worked for me. the only difference being that I removed `theme=tt3` since you didnt provide that

Comment: Weird, what were you viewing the `.svg` output with.  I've tried inskape, illustrator, and firefox, but none of them will display the summary table; all I see is the histogram.

Comment: it works in all my browsers, inkscape, and preview/finder

Comment: marrangeGrob is for multiple pages, I don't think svg supports that. Note that the ggsave hack is no longer applicable, and not needed with the latest ggplot2.

Comment: I'm still not sure why it works for rawr, can anyone else confirm the `.svgs` containing the histogram and the summary table.

Comment: Thanks for the information @baptiste, I'll see what I can do without `marrangeGrob`.  I did get it to sort of work using `grid.export` from the `gridSVG` package, but the text spacing was a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  Removing previous answer regarding it working under 32bit install and not x64 install because that was not the problem.  Still unsure what was causing the issue, but it is working now.  Leaving the info about `grid.export` as it may be a useful alternative for someone else.

Below is the loop for saving the `.svg's` using `grid.export()`, although I was having some text formatting issues with this (different dataset).

```
for(i in 1:3){
 multi.plots<-marrangeGrob(grobs=(c(rbind(iris.list[i],table.list[i]))),
    nrow=2, ncol=1,heights=c(1.65,.35), top =quote(paste(iris$labels$Species,'\nPage', g, 
    'of',pages)))
prefix<-unique(iris$Species)
prefix<-prefix[i]
filename<-paste(prefix,".svg",sep="")
grid.draw(multi.plots)
grid.export(filename)
grid.newpage()
}
```

**EDIT:** As for using arrangeGrob per @baptiste's comment. Below is the updated code.  I was incorrectly using the single brackets `[]` for the returned `by` list, so I switched to the correct double brackets `[[]]` and used `grid.draw` to on the `ggsave` call.

```
for(i in 1:3){
prefix<-unique(iris$Species)
prefix<-prefix[i]
multi.plots<-grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(iris.list[[i]],table.list[[i]],
   nrow=2,ncol=1,top = quote(paste(iris$labels$Species))))
filename<-paste(prefix,".svg",sep="")
ggsave(filename,grid.draw(multi.plots))
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not simply down to what versions of packages you have installed? BTW use arrangeGrob since you produce one page at a time, and, also, the title probably doesn't work as intended.

Comment: and c+rbind for the grobs is a strange idea, use list()